# Django Ckeditor Save incomplete data from richtextfield to cookies or server

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

The title, in my opinion, is self-explanatory. Basically let’s say a user if filling out an ckeditor richtextfield like so:

```
#app/models.py
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class App_Model(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField()
```

Now let’s say an user left the page. The content will not be saved. I want the content to be saved, whether it be cookies or to the server, so the user can come back and pickup where he left off. How would I do this, preferably in the most simplest way possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to save the content is by using the [CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin](https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin)
plugin for CKEditor 4, which saves the data in an HTML5 LocalStorage (client-side).

You just need to download and add that plugin to the django-ckeditor module.

[Download](https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin/releases) and unpack the `CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin` into your static directory. Make sure that you put the `autosave` folder from the archive into this directory:

```sh
<static-dir>/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/autosave
```

Where `<static-dir>` refers to the directory for your static files. This could be directly inside your app folder (next to admin.py, apps.py etc). For more details check the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/).

Configure your CKEditor by adding this to your `settings.py`

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'extra_plugins': ['autosave'],  # Use the 'autosave' plugin
        'autosave': {                   # Configuration on the autosave plugin
            'autoLoad': True            # Don't ask for confirmation to restore
        }
    },
}
```

For more configuration options check the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-AutoSave-Plugin).